# Adoptable Storage corrupted my SD card

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sd-card, lg, internal-sd, adoptable-storage

I'm using LG Leon on Android 6.0 Marshmallow. LG doesn't allow making SD cards internal storage. I have made my SD Card broken because I used adoptable storage.

I had to use a guide that required me to use ADB. So what I did? I opened ADB, wrote: `sm list:disks` or something similar, and then did type something to format the SD card as internal.

Everything worked for a day or more, and I moved an app (for some reason it didn't automatically save to SD card) and my phone restarted. Then it got into a bootloop, and it wouldn't turn on until I would get my SD card out of the phone. Then my SD card stopped being recognisable (yes, I tried to get it out of the phone and insert it back). Then I pressed "Forget SD card" or something similar. Now my card isn't recognisable on my phone or on my laptop.

Please help me.

Comment: you did nothing wrong. just repeat all steps with another sd card. run `diskmgmt.msc` or `gparted` from terminal for re-partitioning the "broken" one

Comment: @alecxs Could I get a little step-by-step guide? Also, I don't  have a second SD card.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a smartphone can't corrupt an SD-card by using it. The only possibility to degrade an SD-card would be by a large number of writes over a long time (I am talking about months or even years).

Are you sure that the SD-card is really broken? May be you simply need to [re-partition it](https://superuser.com/questions/485756).

In case the card is really dead I see two possibilities:

1. The SD-card you have is a fake, claiming to have more memory than actually available on the flash chips inside. If the SD-card was new and the price was cheap compared to the size than this is the reason for a very high probability. I strongly recommend to test every new SD-card on your PC using a program that allows to identify SD-card fakes like [H2Testw](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/H2testw.shtml)
2. The quality of the SD-card was so poor that something went totally wrong (e.g. overheated) so that the SD-card is now defect.